# Enable CORS on Azure Service Bus Namespace

Tags: azure, cors, azureservicebus

I want to use the Azure Service Bus REST API in JavaScript. Unfortunately I'm running into cross origin problems, as my Service Bus namespace is not in the same domain as my site.

I know that you can enable CORS with many Azure services, but I can't find any resource in the Azure documentation or elsewhere telling me how to do this for the Service Bus.

Does anybody know if, and how, this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this issue by creating a separate Web App with the following `Web.config` which is just a simple proxy.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Proxy" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern=".*" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="https://mynamespace.servicebus.windows.net/{R:0}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
      <serverVariables>
        <set name="HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" value="" />
      </serverVariables>
    </rule>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Expose-Headers" value="BrokerProperties" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: That's essentially what I ended up doing. It seems the best workaround for now until this feature is provided

Comment: 2 questions: A) Is this still the best available solution that you know of (in 2018). And B) what did you do with this web.config? It feels as though you're talking about having a webserver, which has this config and literally nothing else (because it's not doing ANYTHING other than proxying requests through to Azure and hence bypassing CORS.) How did you go about setting up a webserver with no actual code?

Comment: ad A) I no longer maintain the project where this was used and I am no longer developing applications for Azure but I was discussing this solution with experts from Microsoft and they told me this was the best/preferred solution with the exception that some kind of user authentication like OAuth 2.0 should be added to the service. ad B) Yes, that endpoint/microservice was purely just the proxy. The actual backend for the application was running in other service.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Service Bus REST API supports CORS by default. All origins are accepted.

Answer (score -3):

To be honest this is not an Azure specific. If you are using jQuery you need to enable cross-domain request option, read more here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/. There is also a JavaScript ServiceBus SDK: https://github.com/ddobric/ServiceBusJavaScriptSdk

Generally from the purity point of view calling Service Bus from client side doesn't look good, I'd rather wrap that call into your own API. But I don't know your scenario and it might be valid.

Comment: I disagree that the question isn't Azure specific. CORS is set at the server side, and without it set I will not be able to solve my problem.

Comment: Yeah, I have the same problem, using Service Bus REST API on our web site from JavaScript. Somehow usually it works event when there are error messages in the log but in some rare cases there are "Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://myweb.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404." messages preventing to receive messages from the bus. I cannot explain myself why this sometime works and sometimes don't.

Comment: This is 100% Azure specific. The correct solution to this *SHOULD* be "here is the place in the Azure web portal where you can configure the CORS setting for the service". Unfortunately, Microsoft haven't implemented this yet (insert swearing), so we're left with crappy re-direct workarounds.